# hoe to fix the throw and catch output?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int getSecondSmallest()
{
    unsigned int i;
    int min;
    int num;
    int secondSmallest;

    vector<int> sequence;

    cout << "Enter the numbers in random order: (close by entering q)" << endl;
    for (i = 0; cin.good(); ++i)
    {
        cin >> num;
        sequence.push_back(num);
    }

    sequence.pop_back();
    min = INT32_MAX;
    secondSmallest = INT32_MAX;

    for (i = 0; i < sequence.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (sequence.at(i) < min)
        {
            secondSmallest = min;
            min = sequence.at(i);
        }
        if (sequence.at(i) != min && sequence.at(i) < secondSmallest)
        {
            secondSmallest = sequence.at(i);
        }
    }

    if (secondSmallest >= INT32_MAX)
    {
        throw runtime_error("error:");
    }

    cout << "The second smallest number is: " << secondSmallest << endl;

    return secondSmallest;

}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        int secondSmallest;
        secondSmallest = getSecondSmallest();
    }
    catch (runtime_error & except)
    {
        cout << except.what() << " no second smallest" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a program that gives the second smallest of sequense. It should have an error as output if the sequence is : 1 1 1 q and if the sequence is: -3 2147483647 q. With this code i get error for both. How should i fix this? I am not allowed to sort the list. So it should be this way..
    }

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger, while investigating the values of variables, at each execution step?

Comment: Suggestion rather than putting a garbage value into the sequence and then popping it back out, don't put it in in the first place. `while (cin >> num) { sequence.push_back(num); }`